# controller availablity in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jsp

I am unable to access the secondcontroller and secondsercice in the Base.jsp or first.jsp.
But I am able to view the secondcontroller and secondsercice  in the inspect elements.
if I observe ng-click in the insect elements `<a href="javascript: void(0);" class="ng-binding"`.

If I execute second.jsp then the controller and service is working and getting the data in onload.
when I use the below process I am not getting onload data.
How can I make work the below process like second.jsp

**Base.jsp**

```
<%@include file="CacheBustUrl.jsp" %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="myController.js" ></script>

</head>
<body  ng-app="myApp"  
    ng-controller="myController">

     <onload-documents-directive></onload-documents-directive>
     <get-documents></get-documents>


</div>
    <jsp:include page="first.jsp"></jsp:include>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**first.jsp**.

```
<%@include file="CacheBustUrl.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body onload-documents-directive>
<div class="modal fade rotate" id="firstPopup">
        <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:1032px !important;">
            <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <jsp:include page="second.jsp"></jsp:include>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**second.jsp**

```
<%@include file="CacheBustUrl.jsp"%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="${secondControllerjs}"></script>
<script src="${secondServicejs}"></script>
<script src="${cbemptyCheckerjs}"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" onload-documents-directive
    ng-controller="secondController" 
     ng-init="mySwitch=true" disable-keys>
</body>
</html>
```